# Switch between Prod and Dev environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've built a REST Service with Spring Boot. The setup in the development environment is different from the setup in the production environment. What is the best approach to switching setup between development environment and production environment? By setup I mean for instance the path to the database that is different in development vs. production. I can think of three approaches, use environment variables, use a properties file or use config file. Other suggestions are welcome and what I should think about when choosing.

Comment: Have you tried Spring profiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at Spring Profiles - [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). Using spring profile, u can easily switch configurations for the different environments.

Just name your configuration for "dev" as "application-dev.(properties|yaml) and provide *-Dspring.profiles.active=dev* when running the App from command line.

Comment: I'll deploy my app on PaaS as a WAR file on a Tomcat server. Will I still be able to use Spring Profiles?

Comment: To be honest, I have no experience with that. However, what you can definitely do is, to provide a base configuration file, called "bootstrap.yml". Spring boot will pick this one first. Here you could set the property "spring.profiles.active", thus you are not longer depending on startup parameters.

Comment: Great. I'll give that a try.